# Checking and unchecking radio buttons with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I can't check a set of checkboxes programatically with jquery mobile, I have the following code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain"  id="div_radio" class="radiogroup">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-pieces" id="radio-choice-1" value="3" checked="checked" />
        <label for="radio-choice-1">1 to 3</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-pieces" id="radio-choice-2" value="5"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-2">4 to 5</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-pieces" id="radio-choice-3" value="6"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-3">over 5</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

If I do: `$("input[type='radio']:last").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");` everything works perfect, but none of this work at all:

```
$("input[type='radio']:first").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
$("input[type='radio']:eq(0)").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
$("input[type='radio']:eq(1)").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
$("input[type='radio']:eq(2)").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

How can I properly manipulate these elements? Unselecting all checkboxes also works fine:

```
$("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

It seems that the only checkbox working is the last one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They all work just fine. You just need to trigger `refresh` on all `input radio` in group.

```js
$("input[type='radio']:first").attr("checked", "checked");
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/xA5jC/).

Answer (score 5):

Nothing worked for me except:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#Store').trigger("click").trigger("click"); // yes... twice
});
```

On jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

For me works this to uncheck the whole group of radios:

```
$(".my_class").removeAttr("checked");
$(".my_class").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem right.
The single quote is not needed input[type=radio] is correct.
I'm using an outdated version (1.1.1).
It would be help to know what version you're using.

Keep in mind that those are radio buttons, only one selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

in Jquery mobile radio button refresh like  this:

```
$(".iscfieldset input[type='radio']:first").attr("checked", "checked");


    $(".iscfieldset input[type='radio']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
```

try this working fine for me