# Checking and unchecking radio buttons with Jquery Mobile 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I try reproduce [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409571/checking-and-unchecking-radio-buttons-with-jquery-mobile) with Jquery Mobile 1.3.2, but it works only with version 1.2.1 or less.

```
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){

        $("#checkFirst").click(function(){
            $("input[type='radio']:first").attr("checked", "checked");
            $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
        });
        $("#checkSecond").click(function(){
            $("input[type='radio']:eq(1)").attr("checked", "checked");
            $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
        });
        $("#checkLast").click(function(){
            $("input[type='radio']:last").attr("checked", "checked");
            $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
        });
        $("#uncheckAll").click(function(){
            $("input[type='radio'][checked]").removeAttr("checked");
            $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
        });
    });
```

This function redraw radiobuttons only 1st time for one radiobutton in jqm > 1.2.1

this links to jsfiddle:

[Works version with 1.2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/xA5jC/)
[Don't works version with 1.3.2](http://jsfiddle.net/xA5jC/62/)

Any ideas why this examples don't work in other versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
//to check
$("input[type='radio']:first").prop("checked", true);
//to uncheck
$("input[type='radio']:first").prop("checked", false);
```

Read: [Properties Vs Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("input[type='radio']:first").prop("checked", true);
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)